# Error while installing eclipse android plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse 4.2 IDE for Java Developers and now I'm trying to install Android plusing and I get this error:

```
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> 
[R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819, action=).
```

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by just removing unzipped main eclipse directory and .eclipse directory in my home directory and starting it again!

Answer (score 1):

First you should install JDK. then please refer below link 
this will solve your problem.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: i have followed these and didnt help. i have JDK 1.6 working on my Debian Linux.

Comment: Are you  using with ADT 20.0.0 ?

Comment: yes i think! according to logs, eclipse is trying to install ADT 20.0.0

Comment: Download ADT-20.0.0.zip from above link.then uninstall ADT through eclipse and configure new ADT using with ADT-20.0.0.zip

Comment: How are you trying to download the adt plugin?

Comment: i have downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html which is 12MB and followed the instruction to install it but failed with same error!